# Unable to render Vue, Graphql app on Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, vue.js, graphql

I'm having issues rendering my application only when I try to push to Heroku. Everything runs fine when running locally though.

I have a webpack cli vue setup. Here's a snippet of my **package.json** file:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build",
  },
```

The heroku-postbuild command I got from an [online tutorial](https://wyeworks.com/blog/2018/1/8/how-to-quickly-deploy-a-vuejs-app-to-heroku/)

I believe my main issue is in my **server.js** file, which is located in the root folder:

```
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express')
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql')
const schema = require('./server/schema.js')
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
}))

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
    })
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('GraphQL API server running at localhost:'+ port);
})
```

Lastly, in my vuejs **main.js** file I have to define my graphql uri. How am I supposed to know what port number to use since it's dynamic after getting deployed?

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'

import App from './App'
import router from './router'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

require('./main.css')

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:3000/graphql' : 'https://localhost:5667/graphql')
})

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    connectToDevTools: true
})

Vue.use(VueApollo)

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: apolloClient,
    defaultOptions: {
        $loadingKey: 'loading'
    }
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    apolloProvider,
    router,
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>'
})
```

I've been trying many different configurations and can't seem to get past this. I've searched lots of posts and tutorials without any success

Answer (score 0):

If your port is dynamically set for GraphQL server, but not your http server, then a solution you could go with is to add a route on your server to get the port for GraphQL and return it to the client. You would then initiate your HTTPLink object and use the port returned from the server.

Comment: I tried wrapping all the setup code into a call but the app never gets rendered at all due to it being an asynchronous process